Can't find xpath or css selector to this specific text area in copilot web page document mode
I'm trying to automate a task on the Copilot site.
I want to click inside the first text area which is visible using this XPath
/html/body/div[3]/cib-serp//cib-notebook/cib-action-bar//div/div/div/div[1]/cib-text-input//form/label/textarea

that I got using inspect element selecting full XPath. The problem is that when I paste it into the XPather extension, it says no result.
Is there any way that I can get access to this TEXTAREA and put some text via Selenium to automate the process?

The main problem is that they've protected the page somehow so that you can't automate it. All my attempts to find the question box and put text in it have failed. That's why your extension said that the element can't be found... because the page is blocking it from being found.

While we're here and you're new, here are some suggestions...

I'm not sure why the XPath you copied is so long. I would suggest that you take some time to learn to create your own locators, CSS selectors and XPaths.
The TEXTAREA element that you are looking for is

<textarea class="text-area" id="searchbox" name="searchbox" type="text" rows="1" dir="" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both" spellcheck="false" aria-label="Ask me anything..." enterkeyhint="send" autocorrect="off" maxlength="2000" placeholder="Ask me anything..." autofocus=""></textarea>

You can see that it has an ID, id="searchbox", which is the preferred locator because it's the least likely to change if the page is updated, etc. To use that, you will declare a locator, e.g. for python it would be (By.ID, "searchbox"). Other languages have equivalent By declarations.

The other issue on this page is that it's got several nested shadow-roots. One example is below
<cib-serp class="cib-serp-main" alignment="center" mode="conversation" chat-type="consumer" product="bing" side-panel="" tone="Balanced" data-bm="5" service="" scenario="" feed="" serp-slot="none">
  #shadow-root (open)

In order to access these, you need to find them and switch into them to view the elements inside, e.g.
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'shadow_content')

I was able to get one layer deep before the page stopped returning values. I'm suspecting this is where they've put in the anti-script protections.


Anyway, if the page was able to be automated, the script would look like the below.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://copilot.microsoft.com/'
driver.get(url)

question = "How do I get a job with Microsoft?"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
shadow_root1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-serp"))).shadow_root
shadow_root2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cib-action-bar-main").shadow_root
shadow_root3 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-text-input").shadow_root
shadow_root3.find_element(By.ID, "searchbox").send_keys(f"{question}\n")


This is the element that you are looking for <cib-text-input alignment="left" chat-type="consumer" mode="notebook" product="bing" serp-slot="none" speech-state="hidden" fixed-size v2>"
This is the CSS selector that you can use: cib-text-input[chat-type="consumer"] { yourCss: yourCss; } or any other attribute

how can if find its xpath which will let me paste my text in it.
